# Tool for resolving variables/constants values without being executing the java code

Tags: java, parser, static-code-analysis

I am looking for tool/library to help me parse the actual values of objects/variables/constants of non-compiled Java code.

> String sql = excludeNotReadyForMatching ? SELECT_RELATED_INVOICE_IDS_BY_POID : SELECT_RELATED_INVOICE_IDS_BY_POID_WITH_NOT_READY_FOR_MATCHING; if(!excludeNotReadyForMatching && includeReturnDrafts) { sql= sql.replaceFirst(INCLUDE_WF_DRAFT_CONDITION, INCLUDE_WF_RETRUNED_CONDITION); } try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)).

Consider this example I want to parse (what actual query will be passed into) this sql which is inside `.prepareStatment()` method.

I apologize for my mistakes in explaining the matter.